# How to connect pi zero w to the internet?

Tags: wifi, pi-zero, connection

I recently got a zero W. The main reason I got it was so that I wouldn't need to drastically increase the size of my projects by adding a wifi and bluetooth module. However, on a clean install of Raspian, when I go to startx and try to connect it to the internet, it says "no wireless interfaces found." Do I need to install a special library? Is my pi broken? Thanks!

Comment: Automatically shows on mine, albeit takes a few seconds to load

Comment: Run the command raspi-config https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I got my Raspberry Pi Zero W

All you have to do is go into

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/`
you'll see a file called
`wpa_supplicant.conf`

just add

```
network={
  ssid="your network name"
  psk"your password"
}
```

Then reboot your raspberry Pi 
 note that you will have to use sudo to edit `wpa_supplicant.conf`